# Why can't I load up a local JSON file with AngularJS $http?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, web-applications

I am trying to load up local file(`todo.json`) that is in the same folder as my webpage with the following line:

```
$http.get("todo.json").success( function( data ){ //Do Some logic});
```

But I get the following error message in the Javascript console:

```
Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/quickCoder/Desktop/HTML5Apps/todo.json'.
...
```

As mentioned, the `index.html` file consisting of this code is in the same `HTML5Apps` folder as `todo.json`. Any suggestions ?

Comment: 1. Is your JSON format valid? 2. Is your server config valid for representing the JSON format? 3. Where is your controller/service?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. The file is not on a server. It is on a local folder. 3. Controller is omitted...everything works except this line.

Comment: You cannot use requests to server if you don't run the files on server.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a running webserver that serves your files and the json file have to be in the folder of your server.

You can use a server like [node-serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-serve). It's easy to run once installed just type `serve` in your terminal.

> [...] Now the protocol for a local file is not http:// but file://. Therefore, you cannot do a direct AJAX request from a local file. The same applies to many other APIs available through JavaScript, which can only request access through the HTTP protocol. This is because of the Web's security model, which we'll discuss in another article.

source of the quote [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Open_a_file_in_a_browser)